# How to limit cache of internet browsers?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-ace

I use the default browser as well Opera Mini.
I can't seem to find any setting to limit the cache to a certain amount (in MB for example).
They eat up disk space quickly.

Anyone knows if it's possible limit the cache disk usage of these browsers?
If not, can you recommend a browser that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to limit the cache of browsers or apps, however you could use [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.eraser) of many [cache cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.advancedprocessmanager) apps to sweep the cache/temp files in one stroke.

Take a look at [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) as well - it has an option to store the cache on the SD card, so that will eliminate your space problem. There's also the option of clearing the cache/history each time you exit the browser. Also has sync, extensions and Flash support (depending on your device).

BTW - I don't think Opera Mini stores a cache as Opera Mobile does. Opera Mini does however store pages in folders specified by the user.